# Undefined Variable - Custom Post Type Meta

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

I've read many related questions and have tried all that I could so make sure it's actually a duplicate before flagging please.

I've been using WordPress for about 6 years so when I say I'm stuck, I really mean it.

I'm trying to add custom meta boxes to a CPT, `boat`. Below is my code and the error I'm getting.

Error message:

**`Notice: Undefined variable: boat_make in /path/to/file/wp-content/plugins/syb/admin/class-syb-admin.php on line 150`**

This error message is the same for both fields.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Register all of the hooks related to the admin area functionality
 * of the plugin.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @access   private
 */
private function define_admin_hooks() {

    ...

    /**
     * Add metabox and register custom fields
     *
     * @link https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/rock-solid-wordpress-30-themes-using-custom-post-types--net-12093
     */
    $this->loader->add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', $plugin_admin, 'rerender_meta_options' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'save_post', $plugin_admin, 'save_meta_options' );

}

...

/**
 * Save Custom Fields
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function save_meta_options() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( '' ) ) return;
    global $post;

    update_post_meta($post->ID, "customer_id", $_POST["customer_id"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "boat_make", $_POST["boat_make"]);
}

/**
 * Create a meta box for our custom fields
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */ 
public function rerender_meta_options() {
    add_meta_box("boat-meta", "Boat Details", array($this, "display_meta_options"), "boat", "normal", "low");
}

/**
 * Display meta box and custom fields
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */  
public function display_meta_options() {
    global $post; 

    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    var_dump($custom);

    if (isset($custom["customer_id"][0])) {
        $customer_id = $custom["customer_id"][0];
    }  

    ?>
    <label><?php _e( 'Boat Colour:', $this->plugin_name ); ?></label><input name="customer_id" value="<?php echo $customer_id; ?>" /><br>
    <?php 

    if (isset($custom["boat_make"][0])) {
        $boat_make = $custom["boat_make"][0];
    }  

    ?>
    <label><?php _e( 'Boat Make:', $this->plugin_name ); ?></label><textarea name="boat_make"><?php echo $boat_make; ?></textarea>
    <?php
}
```

Loader method:

```
class Syb_Loader {

/**
 * The array of actions registered with WordPress.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @access   protected
 * @var      array    $actions    The actions registered with WordPress to fire when the plugin loads.
 */
protected $actions;

/**
 * The array of filters registered with WordPress.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @access   protected
 * @var      array    $filters    The filters registered with WordPress to fire when the plugin loads.
 */
protected $filters;

/**
 * Initialize the collections used to maintain the actions and filters.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function __construct() {

    $this->actions = array();
    $this->filters = array();

}

/**
 * Add a new action to the collection to be registered with WordPress.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @param    string               $hook             The name of the WordPress action that is being registered.
 * @param    object               $component        A reference to the instance of the object on which the action is defined.
 * @param    string               $callback         The name of the function definition on the $component.
 * @param    int                  $priority         Optional. The priority at which the function should be fired. Default is 10.
 * @param    int                  $accepted_args    Optional. The number of arguments that should be passed to the $callback. Default is 1.
 */
public function add_action( $hook, $component, $callback, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 ) {
    $this->actions = $this->add( $this->actions, $hook, $component, $callback, $priority, $accepted_args );
}

/**
 * Add a new filter to the collection to be registered with WordPress.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @param    string               $hook             The name of the WordPress filter that is being registered.
 * @param    object               $component        A reference to the instance of the object on which the filter is defined.
 * @param    string               $callback         The name of the function definition on the $component.
 * @param    int                  $priority         Optional. The priority at which the function should be fired. Default is 10.
 * @param    int                  $accepted_args    Optional. The number of arguments that should be passed to the $callback. Default is 1
 */
public function add_filter( $hook, $component, $callback, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 ) {
    $this->filters = $this->add( $this->filters, $hook, $component, $callback, $priority, $accepted_args );
}

/**
 * A utility function that is used to register the actions and hooks into a single
 * collection.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @access   private
 * @param    array                $hooks            The collection of hooks that is being registered (that is, actions or filters).
 * @param    string               $hook             The name of the WordPress filter that is being registered.
 * @param    object               $component        A reference to the instance of the object on which the filter is defined.
 * @param    string               $callback         The name of the function definition on the $component.
 * @param    int                  $priority         The priority at which the function should be fired.
 * @param    int                  $accepted_args    The number of arguments that should be passed to the $callback.
 * @return   array                                  The collection of actions and filters registered with WordPress.
 */
private function add( $hooks, $hook, $component, $callback, $priority, $accepted_args ) {

    $hooks[] = array(
        'hook'          => $hook,
        'component'     => $component,
        'callback'      => $callback,
        'priority'      => $priority,
        'accepted_args' => $accepted_args
    );

    return $hooks;

}

/**
 * Register the filters and actions with WordPress.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function run() {

    foreach ( $this->filters as $hook ) {
        add_filter( $hook['hook'], array( $hook['component'], $hook['callback'] ), $hook['priority'], $hook['accepted_args'] );
    }

    foreach ( $this->actions as $hook ) {
        add_action( $hook['hook'], array( $hook['component'], $hook['callback'] ), $hook['priority'], $hook['accepted_args'] );
    }

}

}
```

Comment: if the `$custom[boat_make][0]` is not set, then the variable is never created, no default value is ever set!

Comment: @TomJNowell the question is why, it should of been set with `save_meta_options()`

Comment: After the initial save yes, but beforehand..

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, figured it out. Was a simple mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saving your meta data, you have `if ( ! current_user_can( '' ) ) return`

I've never run current_user_can against and empty string of capabilities, so I'm not sure what your results are going to be, but it's very possible this returns a false, and you return at this point.

Also, be sure you sanitize your $_POST data before sticking it in the database.

Comment: this was it! don't know why that caused the problem

Comment: Probably because the empty string is not a valid capability, so you are asking if the user has this capability, and WP says no.  If No, return.

Answer (score 0):

It's not even that $custom["boat_make"][0], but not even $custom["boat_make"] is set.

Because of that, you cannot ask: `if (isset($custom["boat_make"][0]))`

Check your database and see if the post meta exists for "boat_make"

What does it look like when you do your `var_dump($custom);` ?

Comment: No it’s not set